# Magento 2 : Translation Error

Tags: magento2, localisation, inline-translations

I have magento 2.1.3, with two store Arabic and English. I set languages each for store view.

I went **production mode** did **static content deploy** and enabled **compress and minify js and css**.

I see some arabic strings translated in English store view and not all translated strings appear.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in Magento 2.1.3 which breaks js translations. The bug is already reported, see this link for more info and a workaround: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7862